# Angular Material Table Error: Can't bind to 'mdHeaderRowDef' since it isn't a known property of 'md-header-row'

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-datatables, angular-cdk

I'm trying to convert a CDK data-table to a Material Design styled data-table (see: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview), but when I change the cdk prefixes to md, I get the following error...

---

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'mdHeaderRowDef'
>   since it isn't a known property of 'md-header-row'.
>   1. If 'md-header-row' is an Angular component and it has 'mdHeaderRowDef' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'md-header-row' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message.
>   3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

---

Every answer I've found online tells me that I need to import CdkTableModule, but I have done so & cdk tables work perfectly.

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk';
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

I am importing CdkTableModule, and when I use the cdk prefix, the table displays as expected...

```html
<md-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="number">
    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> number </md-header-cell>
    <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let element"><a routerLink="{{element.number}}"> {{element.number}} </a></md-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="book">
    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> book </md-header-cell>
    <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let element"> {{element.book}} </md-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="['number', 'book']"></md-header-row>
  <md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: ['number', 'book']"></md-row>
</md-table>
```

**RESULT: So far so good**... 
[image]
but if i change "cdk" to "md"

```html
<md-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

  <ng-container mdColumnDef="number">
    <md-header-cell *mdHeaderCellDef> number </md-header-cell>
    <md-cell *mdCellDef="let element"><a routerLink="{{element.number}}"> {{element.number}} </a></md-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container mdColumnDef="book">
    <md-header-cell *mdHeaderCellDef> book </md-header-cell>
    <md-cell *mdCellDef="let element"> {{element.book}} </md-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <md-header-row *mdHeaderRowDef="['number', 'book']"></md-header-row>
  <md-row *mdRowDef="let row; columns: ['number', 'book']"></md-row>
</md-table>
```

**RESULT: Broken :(**
[image]

I've tried importing other modules... including MdTableModule & MdTable, but that hasn't proven helpful either. Any ideas?

P.S. Here's my main app.module.ts import statement in case that helps

```
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
HttpModule,
AppRoutingModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
MdAutocompleteModule,
MdButtonModule,
MdButtonToggleModule,
MdCardModule,
MdCheckboxModule,
MdChipsModule,
MdTableModule,
MdDatepickerModule,
MdDialogModule,
MdExpansionModule,
MdGridListModule,
MdIconModule,
MdInputModule,
MdListModule,
MdMenuModule,
MdCoreModule,
MdPaginatorModule,
MdProgressBarModule,
MdProgressSpinnerModule,
MdRadioModule,
MdRippleModule,
MdSelectModule,
MdSidenavModule,
MdSlideToggleModule,
MdSliderModule,
MdSnackBarModule,
MdSortModule,
MdTabsModule,
MdToolbarModule,
MdTooltipModule,
MdNativeDateModule,
CdkTableModule,
StyleModule
 ]
```

Comment: Which version of material?

Comment: I figured it out!

Comment: I updated to  "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.10" and changed the DataSource import to: import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk/table' and the CdkTableModule import to: import { CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table' ... and alas it works!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After another hour of fiddling with things, I ran

> npm update --save

and updated @angular/cdk and @angular/material to 2.0.0-beta.10

in package.json

```
 "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
 "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
```

This broke some things, so I had to dig around and needed to update imports of DataSource and CdkTableModule

```
       import { CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
       import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk/table';
```

component.html

```
 <md-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container mdColumnDef="number">
      <md-header-cell *mdHeaderCellDef> number </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell *mdCellDef="let element"><a routerLink="{{element.number}}"> {{element.number}} </a></md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container mdColumnDef="book">
      <md-header-cell *mdHeaderCellDef> book </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell *mdCellDef="let element"> {{element.book}} </md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container mdColumnDef="s1">
      <md-header-cell *mdHeaderCellDef> S1 </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell *mdCellDef="let element"> {{element.sections[0] ? element.sections[0].type : ''}} {{element.sections[0] && element.sections[0].qs ? '('+element.sections[0].qs.length+')' : ''}}</md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container mdColumnDef="s2">
      <md-header-cell *mdHeaderCellDef> S2 </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell *mdCellDef="let element"> {{element.sections[1] ? element.sections[1].type : ''}} {{element.sections[1] && element.sections[1].qs  ? '('+element.sections[1].qs.length+')' : ''}} </md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container mdColumnDef="s3">
      <md-header-cell *mdHeaderCellDef> S3 </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell *mdCellDef="let element"> {{element.sections[2] ? element.sections[2].type : ''}} {{element.sections[2] && element.sections[2].qs ? '('+element.sections[2].qs.length+')' : ''}}</md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container mdColumnDef="s4">
      <md-header-cell *mdHeaderCellDef> S4 </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell *mdCellDef="let element"> {{element.sections[3] ? element.sections[3].type : ''}} {{element.sections[3] && element.sections[3].qs ? '('+element.sections[3].qs.length+')' : ''}}</md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <md-header-row *mdHeaderRowDef="['number', 'book', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4']"></md-header-row>
    <md-row *mdRowDef="let row; columns: ['number', 'book', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4']"></md-row>
  </md-table>
```

component.ts

```
 import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

 // Data Table imports.
     import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/table';
     import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
     import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-start',
   templateUrl: './start.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./start.component.css']
 })
 export class StartComponent implements OnInit {

   pts: Pt[];
   dataSource = new ExampleDataSource(this.ptService);
   constructor( public ptService: PtService ) { }
   ngOnInit() {
     this.pt = this.ptService.getPts();
   }
 }

 export class ExampleDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
   data = this.ptService.getPts();
   constructor( public ptService: PtService ) { super() }
   /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
   connect(): Observable<Pt[]> {
     return Observable.of(this.data);
   }
   disconnect() {}
 }
```

Phew!

Comment: please accept your answer so that others can also benefit in case of a similar issue

Answer (score 13):

import `MatTableModule` in app.module.ts

```
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
     MatTableModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since "^2.0.0-beta.11" all the selectors that start with `md` are not valid and should be replaced with `mat` so you have to replace all of them, in material website the documents do not seem to be updated yet.

Answer (score 0):

All types of tables have her own prefix if you use one type you have to use her prefix. It's clear like that